# Vue.js select placeholder disappears on input click

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js

I am using Vue.js to bind input values to a form and I am having a weird issue with the drop downs. When I click ANY other input on the page, the select placeholders dissappear and they look like empty fields. If you click the dropdown, the values are still there and you can select an item but I need to avoid having the placeholders dissappear.

HTML

```
<div class="review-form hidden" id="submit-form">
            <form action="">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h6 class="required">How would you rate this product?</h6>
                        <div class="mt-1">
                            <fieldset class="rating" id="rating">
                                <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" v-model="rating" checked/><label class = "full" for="star5"></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" v-model="rating" /><label class = "full" for="star4"></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" v-model="rating" /><label class = "full" for="star3"></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" v-model="rating" /><label class = "full" for="star2"></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" v-model="rating" /><label class = "full" for="star1"></label>
                            </fieldset>
                            <span class="star-label upper"><span class="chosen-rating">((rating)) Star<span v-if="rating > 1">s</span></span></span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Full Name</h6>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your full name (i.e John Smith)" v-model="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h6 class="required mt-2">Email Address</h6>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" v-model="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Twitter</h6>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="@twitter" v-model="twitter">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="required mt-2">City</h6>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your city" v-model="city">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <h6 class="mt-2">State</h6>
                        <div class="select">
                            <select class="form-control" id="form-states" v-model="state">
                                <option>Select State</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Age</h6>
                        <div class="select">
                            <select class="form-control" id="form-age" v-model="age">
                                <option>Select Age</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Title</h6>
                        <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="4 or 5 words about Public Information Services" v-model="title">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Review</h6>
                        <input name="review" type="text" placeholder="How have you enjoyed your Public Information Services experience?" v-model="review">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <a  class="btn btn-success mb-1 search-private-btn btn-transformed pull-right">Submit a Review</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
  </div>
```

JS

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#submit-form',
  data: {
      rating: 5,
      name: '',
      email: '',
      twitter: '',
      city: '', 
      state: '',
      age: '',
      title: '',
      review: ''
  },
  delimiters: ["((","))"]
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var footerList = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-link');
    openInNewTab(footerList);

    ageInput();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.review-form').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 300);
});

function submitReview(rating, name, email, twitter, city, state, age, title, review) {
    var dto = {
        rating: rating,
        name: name,
        email: email,
        twitter: twitter,
        city: city,
        state: state,
        age: age,
        title: title,
        review: review
    }

    $.post("/api/submitReview", dto, function(res){
        if (res.ok) {
            $('.review-form').addClass('hidden');
            $('.thank-you').removeClass('hidden');
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your default options to show, they should have the same `value` as the initial value of the property in `data`. They should also be declared `disabled` just in case.

So all you need to do is replace the two `option` tags with this:

```
<option disabled value="">Select State</option>

<option disabled value="">Select Age</option>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much.